# Hadoop - error message when declaring variable within query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have tried the following query within HUE's Beeswax Query Editor:

```
SET MAXDATE=(SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.SOURCE_TABLE

WHERE YEAR(DATA_DAY) >= '2015'
AND DATA_DAY > ${HIVECONF:MAXDATE};
```

This query will not run and produces the following error message:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:4 missing KW_ROLE at 'MAXDATE' near 'MAXDATE' line 1:11 missing EOF at '=' near 'MAXDATE'

Any advice on what the problem is?  I don't understand what the KW_ROLE message means.

I come from a SQL Server background and would just run the following within SQL Server, but am trying to find a functional Hadoop/Hive equivalent.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.SOURCE_TABLE

WHERE YEAR(DATA_DAY) >= '2015'

AND DATA_DAY > (SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `hive` support the following syntax too.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.SOURCE_TABLE a

JOIN 

(SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) AS max_date FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE) b

WHERE YEAR(a.DATA_DAY) >= '2015'

AND a.DATA_DAY > b.max_date;
```

But it's not a good implementation if there are bunches of data on `DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE`.

In such case each query would task lots of sub-querys in `SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE`.

If possible, you could store your `SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE` result in another table, maybe `Max_table`.

Then the sql would be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.SOURCE_TABLE

JOIN Max_table

WHERE YEAR(DB2.SOURCE_TABLE.DATA_DAY) >= '2015' and 

DB2.SOURCE_TABLE.DATA_DAY > (Max_table.DATA_DAY)
```

Comment: Tried the first option, even though it's not optimal. Got the following error related to the last line of the query: **cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MAX' '(' in expression specification**     Will try the option of creating a separate table next. Hope that will work, although it would be ideal if the variable SET command would function.

Comment: Well, updated first option with some test. Now it's a better solution comparing to option 2. @noncentric

Comment: Thank you for this. The second option worked, although it does require creating a separate one record table. I am now trying the revised first option. When you say that it's a "better solution", then do you mean that it's better performance / more optimal?  The fact that it doesn't require a separate table be created is nice.

Answer (score 2):

Query which you have tried contains syntax issue. HiveConf should surrounded by single quotes.

```
SET MAXDATE=(SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB2.SOURCE_TABLE

WHERE YEAR(DATA_DAY) >= '2015'
AND DATA_DAY > '${HIVECONF:MAXDATE}';
```

Comment: With or without the quotes, the error message is the same. The error message indicates that it's not progressing past the first line (SET...) due to a KW_ROLE issue, so with/without quotes is not causing this issue.

Comment: Are you sure `hive` support `SET MAXDATE=(SELECT MAX(DATA_DAY) FROM DB1.DESTINATION_TABLE);` ??

Comment: @noncentric : how are you executing the above command? through hive terminal or through any shell script? becaz it is working for me..Also have you added any parameters or comments above the query?

Comment: @Nithiyanandhan -- I tried running the SET query via HUE Beeswax query editor. I tried it both with and without Settings of hive.execution.engine = tez.             I get the same missing KW_ROLE error message every time I try to run the query.

Comment: I suspect it's not the syntax of the query that is the problem, as I had also read that the SET statement should work...which is why I tried it initially.  Rather, I think the problem is related to KW_ROLE and whatever that error message means.  I haven't been able to find any info on this error message (KW_ROLE).